# Does Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 Include a TFS server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, and was told it included a TFS server.  However I am unsure of if it has/can be installed, or how to start it up if it has been.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me please?

Thanks :)

Thanks for your help :)

I am downloading the ISO of the separate product instead from [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=58665c27-7023-4a50-b31d-c39cd86a415f&displaylang=en).

Comment: Probably you've seen that VS 2010 does include source control. It's called Visual SourceSafe.

Comment: no I was at a Microsoft event this week and they mentioned it. Eww source safe :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, beta 2 doesn't include in VS 2010 a TFS. but you can get the beta for TFS 2010 seperate.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I was told part of the 3 licenses (professional, premium and ultimate) an instance of TFS would be included.  I assumed it would come bundled with visual studio.

Comment: Ultimate is the new version of VS Team System Architect. Premium is like Team System Developer, database or what so ever. Professional is as always professional. You can download for testing purposes beta 2 of TFS here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c70fd8f-615e-4203-a028-acb2c2b8b88f&displaylang=en#filelist

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 with MSDN will include TFS.  The MSDN subscription is what licenses you for TFS 2010.  You still need a licensed Windows server on which to install it.  TFS needs an installation of SQL Server to run.  You may use an existing server or you are licensed to run an instance of SQL 2008 express on the application server with TFS 2010.

I believe that you can use the "Go Live" licensing with the 2010 RC now if you already have a subscription.